# How do I change the pip install location on MacOS?

Tags: python, terminal, pip, jupyter

I have downloaded both Anaconda3 and Python 3.9 on my MacBook. However, when I use the command pip install, pip downloads the packages here:

```py
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages
```

Because of this, I cannot download any packages that I can use in Jupyter Notebook. Is there any way to change the pip install location or change Jupyter's Python distribution?

Thank you!